# How To Bind Image Source in C# (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In My Project,I Create Some Images with C# and i want these photo's sources, Bind to a property in My ViewModel.

in My MVVM :

```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private string _Light= "dark.png";

        public string Light
        {
            get { return _Light; }
            set {
                _Light = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Light)));
            }
        }
```

in My C#:

```
BindingContext = new LightViewModel();
LightViewModel light = new LightViewModel();
Image dark = new Image { Margin = new Thickness(0, -5, 0, 10), HeightRequest = 20, WidthRequest = 20 };
dark.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, light.Light);
```

i use exactly this MVVM with this Xaml, and it's Property work

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Light}" ></Image>
```

Can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the second parameter of `SetBinding` method is the name of the property, not the property itself, so what you should do is something like this:

```
dark.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "Light");
```